# XAML: Adding Featured item in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, win-universal-app

I have this design problem that I can't figure out how to do or don't even know what its called that's why its so hard for me to google it.

I have a ListView and wanted to add a "Featured" item in there that has a triangle corner at the upper right corner with text "Featured". Something like this[image]

Here is the sample code

XAML

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView x:Name="lstproductstype" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" SelectionMode="None" IsActiveView="True"  Background="Transparent">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-1"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Width="590" Background="White" Height="220" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="txtblktype" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontSize="21"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

CS

```
    MyData data1 = new MyData();
    data1.id = 1;
    data1.IsFeatured = true;
    data1.Name = "Featured Item 1";
    myDatas.Add(data1);


    MyData data2 = new MyData();
    data2.id = 2;
    data2.IsFeatured = true;
    data2.Name = "Featured Item 2";
    myDatas.Add(data2);

    MyData data3 = new MyData();
    data3.id = 3;
    data3.IsFeatured = false;
    data3.Name = "Ordinary Item 3";
    myDatas.Add(data3);

    MyData data4 = new MyData();
    data4.id = 4;
    data4.IsFeatured = false;
    data4.Name = "Ordinary Item 4";
    myDatas.Add(data4);
    lstproductstype.ItemsSource = myDatas;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the easiest way is to use polygon. Just have to figure out how to write text diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is below
Create a image as above in any tool 
Then use 2 columns in each cell with 2nd row having the image

Based on the hide the image.

This should be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Make a featured.png with a transparent background and the text. Then also make a converter from boolean to a Visibility. And then just put that image on top of the textblock in your border where you have grids on top of each other.

```
<Border ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock .../>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="featured.png" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Visibility="{Binding IsFeatured, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Create converter as a resource like in the window / usercontrol.

```
<custom:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
```